# locate command with regular expression to locate multiples file at a time

Tags: regex, grep

There are files like `compile.x86.log` `compile.x86.log-1` `compile.x86.log-2` `compile.x86.log-3` and `error.log` `error.log_1` `error.log_2` `error.log_3` want to use locate command to locate only `compile.x86.log` and `error.log` among them.

So far I tried

```
echo $(/usr/bin/locate -ir '^/\([^.][^/]\+/\)\+compile.x86\.log$')
echo $(/usr/bin/locate -ir '^/\([^.][^/]\+/\)\+error\.log$')
```

With above individual approach it taking search/execution time as 0m18.068s.

How to combine above two?
Also please provide if some other better solution available only with locate command preferably with `locate -b` option to search exact names as (compile.x86.log and error.log) in less time.

I have tried `echo $(/usr/bin/locate -i -b "compile.x86.log")`
It's taking command execution time 0m1.887s only but returning `compile.x86.log-1` `compile.x86.log-2` `compile.x86.log-3` in result instead of returning only `compile.x86.log` which I don't want.
Is there any way to grep the locate result to return only (compile.x86.log and error.log) in this approach.

Comment: Any particular reason you're focused on the use of the `locate` command?  `find` is more flexible and doesn't require a prior file system scan to have run and pre-cached the data..

Comment: My approach, if you want the speed of a `locate` lookup but the flexibility of a regex search, would be to `locate .log | grep 'your_regex_here'`. At least on the systems I use (BSD and OS X), `locate` doesn't have a `-r` option. If it does on your OS, that's great, but also consider going for portable solutions whenever you can.  Not everyone runs Windows.  Er, Linux.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the locate database outputs entries as absolute path names, and the pattern match test applies to the whole path name (the globbing character `*` does not treat `/` specially),

```
locate -i '*/compile.x86.log' '*/error.log'
```

does what you want.

By the way, the `echo $(…)` around a command seems waste.

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, the most simple answer is:

```
echo $(/usr/bin/locate -ir '^/\([^.][^/]\+/\)\+(compile\.x86|error)\.log$')
```

where `(compile\.x86|error)` is the combination that means "this or this" pattern.

Otherwise, using `find` command would be better:

```
find -type f -name "compile.x86.log" -o -name "error.log"
```